# ResultSet in JCombobox

Tags: java, sql, swing, jcombobox, resultset

I want to populate a Jcombobox with sql results but why am I getting an ArrayIndexOufOfBounds here? The JCombobox is like that: `countrybox = new JComboBox(countries);`

```
    int x = 0;
    String query = "SELECT UNIQUE country FROM criminals ORDER BY country ASC";
    System.out.println(query);
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rset.next()) {
        countries[x] = rset.getString(1);
        x++;
      }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the NullPointerException?

Comment: @AndrewWilkinson  I am really sorry! ArrayIndexOufOfBounds is the error. My mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for temporary storage. You can load the items directly into the combo box with out using an ArrayList:

```
comboBox.addItem(...);
```

Or use a Vector instead of the ArrayList because the DefaultListModel uses a Vector to hold the data anyway.

Comment: +1 from me for pointing the right usage of `JComboBox`, my answer focused only on resolving the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the result set has more elements than the array `countries`. You should use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which grows dynamically instead.

If you absolutely need an array after populating the `ArrayList` then you can obtain it from it using its method [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).

**EDIT**

As suggested by @camickr `JComboBox` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28java.util.Vector%29) which takes a [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) as parameter. Just like an ArrayList a Verctor can also grow automatically. So you can use it instead of the one which takes an array. Better yet, use the method [addItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28java.lang.Object%29) to add elements directly to the combobox.

Comment: Ether add the data directly to the comboBox or add the data to a Vector. Creating an ArrayList is an unnecessary step.

Comment: @Lambros, you might also consider camickr's answer or my eidt.