# Adding a ArrayList into a JComboBox

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jcombobox

I am running into an issue with adding a ArrayList into a JComboBox. Can someone give some advice on how to proceed? I can't seem to get the ArrayList to go into the ComboBox. What are the different ways to work with populating JCombobox's with arrayLists?

HotelSystem.Java

```
package hotelManage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class HotelSystem extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1840835913045151061L;

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel btnPanel;
    private JButton btnRoom;
    private JButton btnCustomer;
    private JButton btnOrder;
    private JButton btnSearch;
    private CardLayout cLayout;
    private JLabel lblUpdate;
    //



    //
    OrderSystem order = new OrderSystem();
    JPanel orderPanel = order.getOrderPanel();
    //
    RoomSystem room = new RoomSystem();
    JPanel roomPanel = room.getRoomPanel();
    ArrayList<String> AvailableRooms = room.getAvailableRooms();
    //
    private JButton btnBackfromRoom = room.getBtnBack();
    private JButton btnBackfromOrder = order.getBtnBack();


    //other
    private JButton btnUserInputEdit = room.getBtnEdit();


    public HotelSystem(){
        showGUI();
        registerListeners();


    }

    private void showGUI(){
        //create JFrame(mainFrame)  
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Hotel Management System");
        mainFrame.setSize(500,300);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));


        //create buttons
        btnRoom = new JButton("Room Editor");
        btnCustomer = new JButton("Customer Editor");
        btnOrder = new JButton("Order");
        btnSearch = new JButton("Search");

        //create Labels
        lblUpdate = new JLabel("Instructions/details will go here.");

        //create main panel 
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        cLayout = new CardLayout();
        mainPanel.setLayout(cLayout);

        //create panel that holds the buttons
        btnPanel = new JPanel();

        //add buttons to panel
        btnPanel.add(btnRoom);
        btnPanel.add(btnCustomer);
        btnPanel.add(btnOrder);
        btnPanel.add(btnSearch);
        btnPanel.add(lblUpdate);


        //Button & Room Panel
        mainPanel.add(btnPanel, "Buttons");
        mainPanel.add(roomPanel, "Rooms");
        mainPanel.add(orderPanel, "Orders");


        //other stuff
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }


    public void registerListeners(){
        //register all buttons to self
        btnRoom.addActionListener(this);
        btnCustomer.addActionListener(this);
        btnOrder.addActionListener(this);
        btnSearch.addActionListener(this);
        btnBackfromRoom.addActionListener(this);
        btnBackfromOrder.addActionListener(this);
        btnUserInputEdit.addActionListener(this);
    } // end registerListeners

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        //check all button presses and send
        //control to appropriate methods
       if (e.getSource() == btnRoom){
           cLayout.show(mainPanel, "Rooms");
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnCustomer){
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnOrder){
            cLayout.show(mainPanel, "Orders");
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnSearch){
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnBackfromRoom){
            cLayout.show(mainPanel, "Buttons");
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnBackfromOrder){
            cLayout.show(mainPanel, "Buttons");
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnUserInputEdit){
            //retrieve contents from ComboBox.
            JComboBox<String> test = room.getRoomType();
            String selectedItem = (String) test.getSelectedItem();

            //adds user input into array
            AvailableRooms.add(selectedItem);



            //testing functionality of.. something.
            for(String item: AvailableRooms){
                System.out.println("retrieved element: " + item);
                lblUpdate.setText("A new room has been created! It has been stored under the " + item + " category.");
                }
            cLayout.show(mainPanel, "Buttons");

        } else {
            //lblOutput.setText("something went wrong");
        } // end if


    } // end actionPerformed




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HotelSystem();

    }


}
```

RoomSystem.Java

```
package hotelManage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RoomSystem {


    private JButton btnEdit;
    private JButton btnBack;
    private JPanel roomPanel;
    private JComboBox<String> roomType;

    GridBagLayout gridBag;

    //RoomPent, RoomLarge, RoomSmall
    String[] roomArray = { "Penthouse", "Large Room", "Small Room" };
    ArrayList<String> AvailableRooms = new ArrayList<String>();


    public RoomSystem(){
        setBtnEdit(new JButton("Create"));
        setBtnBack(new JButton("Back to Main Menu"));

        Label  lblRoom= new Label("Room Type: ");   

        setRoomType(new JComboBox<>(roomArray));



        roomPanel = new JPanel();
        roomPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gridConst = new GridBagConstraints();


        //Panel Dimensions

        gridConst.gridx = 0;
        gridConst.gridy = 0;
        roomPanel.add(lblRoom, gridConst);
        gridConst.gridx = 1;
        gridConst.gridy = 0;
        roomPanel.add(roomType, gridConst);

        gridConst.gridx = 0;
        gridConst.gridy = 2;
        roomPanel.add(getBtnEdit(), gridConst);
        gridConst.gridx = 1;
        gridConst.gridy = 2;
        roomPanel.add(getBtnBack(), gridConst);


    }


    public JPanel getRoomPanel() {
        return roomPanel;
    }


    public void setRoomPanel(JPanel roomPanel) {
        this.roomPanel = roomPanel;
    }


    public JButton getBtnBack() {
        return btnBack;
    }


    public void setBtnBack(JButton btnBack) {
        this.btnBack = btnBack;
    }


    public JButton getBtnEdit() {
        return btnEdit;
    }


    public void setBtnEdit(JButton btnEdit) {
        this.btnEdit = btnEdit;
    }


    public ArrayList<String> getAvailableRooms(){
        return AvailableRooms;

    }

    public void setAvailableRooms(ArrayList<String> AvailableRooms){
        this.AvailableRooms = AvailableRooms;
    }


    public JComboBox<String> getRoomType() {
        return roomType;
    }


    public void setRoomType(JComboBox<String> roomType) {
        this.roomType = roomType;
    }



}
```

OrderSystem.Java

```
package hotelManage;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class OrderSystem {

    private JButton btnOrder;
    private JButton btnBack;
    private JPanel orderPanel;
    private JTextField firstName;
    private JTextField lastName;
    //private JComboBox<String> roomList;
    String[] arraynamehere = { "Temp", "Temp1", "Temp2" };
    RoomSystem room = new RoomSystem();
    ArrayList<String> aRooms = room.getAvailableRooms();
    JComboBox<String> roomList;
    //DefaultComboBoxModel<String> Modes = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(); 

    public OrderSystem(){
        btnOrder = new JButton("Process Order");
        setBtnBack(new JButton("Back to Main Menu"));

        JLabel lblfName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
        JLabel lbllName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
        JLabel lblfEmptyRooms = new JLabel("Available Rooms: ");

        firstName = new JTextField("", 20);
        lastName = new JTextField("", 20);


        //ComboBox that should hold the elements of aRooms (Array)
        roomList = new JComboBox<String>();


        orderPanel = new JPanel();
        orderPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gridConst = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Panel Dimensions

        gridConst.gridx = 0;
        gridConst.gridy = 0;
        orderPanel.add(lblfName, gridConst);
        gridConst.gridx = 1;
        gridConst.gridy = 0;
        orderPanel.add(firstName, gridConst);

        gridConst.gridx = 0;
        gridConst.gridy = 1;
        orderPanel.add(lbllName, gridConst);
        gridConst.gridx = 1;
        gridConst.gridy = 1;
        orderPanel.add(lastName, gridConst);

        gridConst.gridx = 0;
        gridConst.gridy = 2;
        orderPanel.add(lblfEmptyRooms, gridConst);
        gridConst.gridx = 1;
        gridConst.gridy = 2;
        orderPanel.add(roomList, gridConst);

        gridConst.gridx = 0;
        gridConst.gridy = 3;
        orderPanel.add(btnOrder, gridConst);
        gridConst.gridx = 1;
        gridConst.gridy = 3;
        orderPanel.add(getBtnBack(), gridConst);


    }




    public JPanel getOrderPanel() {
        return orderPanel;
    }


    public void setOrderPanel(JPanel orderPanel) {
        this.orderPanel = orderPanel;
    }

    public JButton getBtnBack() {
        return btnBack;
    }


    public void setBtnBack(JButton btnBack) {
        this.btnBack = btnBack;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }

}
```

Comment: Please change your question to use a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: Can you show me how to add a ArrayList to a JComboBox?

Comment: What makes you think you are not properly referencing the Arraylist?  Are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: Do not use `ArrayList`, use Verctor instead in conjunction with this [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28java.util.Vector%29), here a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19199031/1113392)

Answer (score 1):

you need to call setModel() on comobox obect.

```
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(aRooms.toArray(new String[aRooms.size()])));
```

see doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setModel%28javax.swing.ComboBoxModel%29)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to work; it still doesn't update

Comment: @user3552931 I am sure. it will set model, I got it you are doing mistake. roomList 'aRooms' is empty in OderSystem calss.

Comment: In RoomSystem class update getAvailableRooms as below                                                          public ArrayList<String> getAvailableRooms(){
     AvailableRooms.addAll(Arrays.asList(roomArray));
        return this.AvailableRooms;
    }                                                               Remember don't forget to setModel in OrderSystem class for roomList combobox

Comment: I think I do that in the HotelSystem under actionPerformed(ActionEvent e). By the time the array reaches OrderSystem, it doesn't seem to be populated.

Comment: In RoomSystem AvailableRooms list in instance variable, it's just empty list, but you are calling getAvailableRooms() from orderSystem class wiht new object of RoomSystem, that's why you are getting empty list and not filling combobox. remember each ojbect has its own copy of instance variables.

Comment: Hmm..How would I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: It's better to initialize in RoomSystem. You need to learn debuging, if it was not populating model that time if you you checked availrooms list, or print it on console, you found it. trust me you will face again and again such type things, so better to learn debug skills, if you got debuging you don't need help of ohters,

Answer (score 0):

A `JComboBox` should be used with a `ComboBoxModel`.

`roomList = new JComboBox<>(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(aRooms.toArray(new String[aRooms.size()));`

This code will create and populate the model for the combobox.

Comment: Didn't work out for some reason. It doesn't give an error during run or anything, but the combobox still doesn't update.

Comment: What is the content of aRooms when the code is run? is it populated?